# What minecraft shaderpack is this?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

The water is "glowing" at night (1:20), and I really like it, but I just can't find it anywhere.. Help me, please!

Comment: I'm not convinced these are shaders, it looks like default minecraft lighting to me. The water might me modded, I know for a fact that many magic mods have glowing water, particularly in certain biomes

Comment: She has a picture of her mods that she put in her description, and there weren't any water or magic mods... But thanks anyways :)

Comment: From the mod list I'd hazard a guess at either Twilight Forest or Fairy Lights

Comment: Thank you, but I actually have the Twilight Forest, and (I think) the Fairy Lights mod only has christmas light decorations. But again, thanks for your help:)

Comment: It looks like a custom texture pack.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I was thinking.. But I have no idea how to make a custom texture pack or shaderpack.. But thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

It probably isn't water and is a substance from one of her mods. It may be from MoreBiomesXL or just a glitch from one of the ModCore shaders excessively reflecting the moonlight.

Answer (score -1):

The mod she is using is called shaders mod core

Answer (score -3):

Shaders has a type of its own The water is not modded is aware for at night times when you go outside to see water it is there and that's how.